# How to remove unwanted program from startup

Tags: windows, popup, malware

[image]

This just started to show up on my Windows10 machine.  No browser is open.  The down arrow includes a "feedback" option that goes to a .cn website.  (I don't understand mandarin!)  Right clicking does nothing.

How do I make this go away?  Is this machine infected?

Comment: Yeah you might get flag for unrelated question. I have edited it.

Comment: @MadeInDreams: How is this question unrelated?

Comment: It's not about coding. SO is a place for code. And the title was a bit discriminatory so I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably something that got install with another package. They often have a checkbox that says install(some crap) and we just click accept without noticing that small checkbox.

You can probably find out what it is by screening trough your running process. Find and destroy that executable. check your mscongif as well.
and you should probably get an Anti Virus.

Comment: Thanks.  It was Flash Helper Service - something I installed weeks ago to investigate elements from a client's old website.  Ending the task in Task Manager got it to go away.  Disabling it in System Configuration keeps it from coming back after a restart.  Windows defender is still on.  All is well now apparently.